# Vb.net: Calling a Function That Does not Match Prototype Passes Compiler Check

Tags: vb.net, function, compiler-construction, syntax-error

I have encountered something I would like explained.  I have a function InitializeValues() that sets up a combobox, and sets the datasource to a datatable. The datatable is retrievedfrom an instance of the class DGVMain_Functions using the public method GetFileSourceData which takes no parameters.
  The issue is that a call to GetFileSourceData(MyConnectionString) will actually compile and run. A run time error occurs when the datatable is returned and attempted to set to the datasource of the cbo. The normal call GetFileSourceData() works properly.
  I had asked another developer about this, and he thought I had some stale reference, so I cleaned the project, then deleted everything in my debug folder, and rebuilt, but it still had the same behavior.

My question is this, Why does the compiler accept this and not throw a syntax error, and furthermore why does it even get to the point where you can actually step into this function that should not exist, and have it fail on return?

**EDIT**: Putting Option Strict On, does make the compiler catch this.   "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Integer'.  But that is still not the error I want to see. I would like to know why it does not display something along the lines of "No such overload/definition of that function exists".

The error is this:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: ERROR: ERROR: Conversion from string "user id=XXXX;data source=XXXXX" to type 'Integer' is not valid.Microsoft.VisualBasicFileProcessor. 
>   "InnerException = {"Input string was not in a correct format."}"

```
Private Sub InitializeValues()
  cboFileSource.DisplayMember = "filesource"
  cboFileSource.ValueMember = "filesource"
  'first call works fine since it matches
  cboFileSource.DataSource = DgvMain_functs.GetFileSourceData()
  'below is the call that gets through the complier and actually runs, fails on return
  cboFileSource.DataSource = DgvMain_functs.GetFileSourceData(MyConnectionString)         
End Sub

Public Function GetFileSourceData() As DataTable
  Try
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim strSQL As String = "select distinct filesource from FileUpload_FolderPath"
    dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(MyConnectionString, CommandType.Text, strSQL).Tables(0)
    Return dt
  Catch ex As Exception
    Throw New Exception("Error in DGVMain_Functions: " & ex.Message & ex.Source)
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I was using the default option, not sure what those are atm.  You are asking about the "explicit" and "strict" option flags right? Now that you have brought that up let me take a look at those.

Comment: Weird. I can confirm it compiles perfectly with Option Strict On and this line `ListBox1.DataSource = GetFileSourceData(CInt("123"))` (`Option Strict` suggests to convert `"123"` via `CInt()`).

Answer (score 0):

As you've hinted in your comment, surely Option Explicit On would solve this issue.

Comment: Actually Option Explicit On did not catch it, only Option Strict On did.  But that still does not explain the issue with a function accepting a parameter when the definition has none. And in my comment I was actually responding to a commenter, but his comment disappered in the past couple minutes for some reason when he asked what flags I had on.